# Jest mock test function inside function Error: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jestjs, babel-jest

This is the selector

```
var getId = function getId(state) {
  return state.ids.id;
};
```

This is the function which I'm trying to write jest for

```
export function triggerUpdate() {
    store.dispatch(retrieveData(getId(store.getState())));
}
```

here is the test which i've written. But test is failing:
Error: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined.

```
describe('triggerUpdate', () => {
    it('should call the update', () => {
        const expectedPayload = [
            { type: 'RETRIEVE_ID', chorusActions: [] },
        ];
        console.log(store.getState()); // this is coming as empty
        const spy = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedPayload);
    });
});
```

I need to mock getId() but tried different ways.

Comment: I suppose your are using React with Redux? Using redux/toolkit?

Comment: You should mock `store` I suppose, not `getId`

Comment: Yes we're using react with redux.

Comment: Solution is relatively simple -put some data in your store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const idSelector = require('path');

describe('triggerUpdate', () => {
    it('should call the update', () => {
        idSelector.getId = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('mockId'); // this is how selector is mocked.

        const expectedPayload = [
            { type: 'RETRIEVE_ID', chorusActions: [] },
        ];
        const spy = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedPayload[0]);
    });
});
```